# Float div and clear using masonry

Tags: jquery, masonry

I have multiple divs using Masonry.

And now, when I click on div sth1,sth3 or any other sth, I want this clicked div to stretch 100% width and lave previous div's where they are and move the rest of the div's down.

This questions works only if browser window gets resized. Try it.

How can I improve this without resizing? Am I missing something?

```js
$(".grid").masonry({ itemSelector: '.grid-item', columnWidth: 10 });

$(".span_1_of_3").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div.grid-item").css({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "250px",
    "position": "relative",
    "left": "0"
  });

  $(this).closest("div.grid-item").prev().next().css({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "250px",
    "position": "relative",
    "left": "0"
  });
});

//ovo je generator razlicitih fontova i boja za tagove
var colors = ['#e74c3c', '#af7ac5', '#5499c7', '#e67e22', '#aab7b8', '#DAF7A6', '#229954', '#f5b7b1', '#f7dc6f', '#7d3c98', '#3498db'];
/*najdi div unutar grid div-a*/
$('.grid').find('.grid-item').each(function(e) {
  //primjeni boju
$(this).css("background-color", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
```

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 200px;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">Sth1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">Sth2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">Sth3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">Sth4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change element dimensions, you need to run masonry again, so that it can calculate the new positions. http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout-masonry // (Masonry itself adds a resize handler to have this covered, when the user resizes the screen. If you do other stuff that requires a re-calculation, then you have to trigger it yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the navigation of CBroe:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
columnWidth: 120
});
$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {

$(this).toggleClass('grid-item--gigante');
$(this).find(".div_to_be_exposed").show();
$grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

And css:

```
.grid-item--gigante {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2; /* above other items */
}
```

Thanks!